# FastCGI: comm with server aborted: read failed

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

One of the php sites hosted on my shared linux/Apache server keeps getting random 500 Internal Server Error, while other sites never encounter any issues. The server error log shows:

Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 1
Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: read failed

Is this an application specific issue or server configuration issue? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you probably have a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your script is over max_execution_time. Maybe 360s

It could be very useful to get which function is consuming most of the execution time. You can use the slow log of php-fpm.

In your pool file (/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf) look for:

- 'slowlog', and add a log file like: '/var/log/php-fpm/www.log.slow'
- 'request_slowlog_timeout', and add a time like: '10s'

Restart php-fpm, tailf this file and maybe you could trace your huge function.

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a try.